# Numpy Arrays - Replacing Elements

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am new to numpy and I want to replace specefic elements in a 3D numpy array. My 3D numpy array represents an image. The shape of the array is: 
(1080, 1920, 3). The number 3 represents RGB of each pixel in the image.

All I want to know is how to change all the elements that are equal to [0,0,0] into [255,255,255]
Which means i want all black pixels in the image to be white.. How can i do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have stored your array in `data`; this should work:

```
data[(data == 0).all(axis=2)] = [255, 255, 255]
```

This is due to `numpy`'s broadcasting rules, which compare each value to 0, resulting in a boolean array with `True` values where they compare equal and `False` elsewhere.

The next step is to take only those sub-arrays where all of the individual values do compare equal, with `.all(axis=2)` - the last axis, which is the one you want.

Then, with the resulting boolean array, you can index back into `data`, which will give you only those sub-arrays equal to `[0, 0, 0]`, and set those to `[255, 255, 255]`.